# Getting IPv6 support with php5-geoip and Maxmind database

Tags: php, geoip

I have geoip setup by following these identical steps (http://php.net/manual/en/geoip.setup.php):

```
wget http://geolite.maxmind.com/download/geoip/database/GeoLiteCity.dat.gz
gunzip GeoLiteCity.dat.gz
sudo mkdir -v /usr/share/GeoIP
sudo mv -v GeoLiteCity.dat /usr/share/GeoIP/GeoIPCity.dat

sudo apt-get install php5-geoip
```

This works brilliantly and has for several years now with IPv4 addresses. I did not, however realize how broken it was with incoming IPv6 devices. For example, it returns `Notice: geoip_country_code_by_name(): Host 26xx:8:xx00:cf20:caxx:ff:fexx:35b5 not found`

I have been through quite a few things attempting to fudge it into working, including:

- testing for v6 address and using `geoip_open("/usr/share/GeoIP/GeoIPv6.dat", GEOIP_STANDARD);`

Apparently geoip_open is not an available function ala php5-geoip

- I have tried using `geoip_country_code_by_name_v6($ip)`

This is another function that is not available even though `geoip_country_code_by_name($ip)` works great.

- I have tried including the missing functions via the geoip.inc file from https://github.com/maxmind/geoip-api-php/blob/master/src/geoip.inc

No avail so far.

Is there any way I can easily, within my PHP code select which database I want to use so that I can simply test whether it is an IPv4 or IPv6 address and load the appropriate database?

Comment: Make sure you're using `GeoLite2`. IPv6 is not supported by the legacy products.

Comment: https://www.maxmind.com/en/ipv6-information-and-faq

Comment: @Barmar if I understand correctly, the Geolite2 binaries are not .dat files and thus could not be used with my current integration with PHP.  I do have the legacy IPv6 dat file but I am unable to indicate which .dat file to lookup in via my PHP code as far as I know.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know the integration process.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to support IPv6->Country code easily and without unnecessary files based on the integration above:

Grab a copy of the latest legacy IPv6 data (I'm assuming you already have IPv4 binary):

```
wget http://geolite.maxmind.com/download/geoip/database/GeoIPv6.dat.gz
```

Decompress and move it to a dir accessible to your web server:

```
gunzip GeoIPv6.dat
mv GeoIPv6.dat /etc/usr/share/GeoIP/GeoIPv6.dat
```

Grab a copy of geoip.inc from the Maxmind git dir (https://github.com/maxmind/geoip-api-php/blob/master/src/geoip.inc) and save it somewhere you can access wherever you'll need to run geoip.

If you have php5-geoip installed as I did, remove it with `sudo apt-get remove php5-geoip`; purge as necessary.

With the above done you can now test incoming IP address for v4 or v6 and get appropriate results.

Example:

```
<?php
include_once('geoip.inc');

//set an IPv6 address for testing
$ip='2601:8:be00:cf20:ca60:ff:fe09:35b5';

/*
test if $ip is v4 or v6 and assign appropriate .dat file in $gi
run appropriate function geoip_country_code_by_addr() vs geoip_country_code_by_addr_v6()   
*/
if((strpos($ip, ":") === false)) {
    //ipv4
    $gi = geoip_open("/usr/share/GeoIP/GeoIP1.dat",GEOIP_STANDARD);
    $country = geoip_country_code_by_addr($gi, $ip);
}
else {
    //ipv6
    $gi = geoip_open("/usr/share/GeoIP/GeoIPv6.dat",GEOIP_STANDARD);
    $country = geoip_country_code_by_addr_v6($gi, $ip);
}
echo $ip . "<br>" . $country;
```

This is specifically for Country, but can easily be replicated for City data.

Answer (score 0):

It is not needed something external for just country info for IPv6. PHP pecl geoip since v1.1.1 from 2016 https://pecl.php.net/package-changelog.php?package=geoip&release=1.1.1 supports 3 new functions `geoip_country_code_by_name_v6()`, `geoip_country_code3_by_name_v6()` and `geoip_country_name_by_name_v6()` which unfortunately are not mentioned in official PHP doc: https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.geoip.php Functions require file GeoIPv6.dat. Note that city info for IPv6 is not supported.

`$countryCode = (strpos($ip, ":") === false) ? geoip_country_code_by_name($ip) : geoip_country_code_by_name_v6($ip);`